# Doing something on email bounce with PHPMailer

Tags: php, email

I am sending messages via SMTP server using `fsockopen`, `fwrite`, and `fgets` functions. How can I check if the email actually exists? I want to remove something from my database in case I try to send an email but it does not exist.

Right now I have some open-source code sending my messages, it does something like this:

```
// send 'DATA' string and check if response is 354
// send message
// send command data string 'DATA_END' and check if it's 250
```

Sending messages look like this:

```
return fwrite($this -> smtp_conn, $data);
```

The class I use exists here:

```
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.smtp.php
```

Does fwrite returns something in case the email does not exist? Or is there a way to catch this?

I don't really have a way to test it for a couple of next days.

Thanks!

Comment: `fwrite()` just returns success if it was able to write the message to the socket. If you want to check the success of sending the message, you have to read the SMTP reply from the server. Note that if you're sending to a relay, it usually just queues the message, so delivery to the destination has not been tested.

Comment: The ***ONLY*** reliable way to check if an email address is valid is to send an email containing a link, and then have the user click on this link. This also has the side-benefit of confirming that the user actually want to receive email from you, helping keep you in compliance with various spam-related laws.

Comment: The thing is I just want to catch the moment where phpmailer library sends email to returnEmail attribute on bounce. But I cant find it, and I dont know how to implement this myself. Any help?